# How to add global tags on geany (windows 8.1)?

Tags: tags, windows-8.1, geany

When I was working with windows 7, i loaded the tags file the directory `C/user/AppData/Roaming/Geany/Tags`, and it worked.
But when i have tried the same method on windows 8.1 , it didn't work. The error message is "could not load tags file"

Comment: Please paste output of Help->Debug into your question

Comment: "unknown filetype for file 'C/user/AppData/Roaming/Geany/Tags/SparksTags.ss.tags' ". ss is our new language. Interesting thing is that it gave the same error on windows 7 before but we have fixed it on windows 7.

Comment: How is your filesdefs file defined?